# Authenticate wp site on LAN to access on cloud site

Tags: wordpress, authentication, active-directory, intranet

I have a WordPress built intranet on my company LAN, we use AD to authenticate staff users on this site using Active Directory Integration plugin.

Now we are migrating this wp intranet site unto AWS where it is far from the reach of our domain controller to keep authenticating with AD.

Getting this configured with AWS will require so much process and approval which will kill our project timelines.

How can we authenticate locally and redirect login into the new site located on AWS?